# Transform data.frame of lists to data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to transform this data.frame

```
              Loc                        Time(h)
  Paris, Luxembourg                      10,15
Paris, Lyon, Berlin                    9,12,11
```

to this

```
Loc               Time(h)
Paris             10
Luxembourg        15
Paris             9
Lyon              12
Berlin            11
```

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(yourdata)` to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Ananda Mahto's [`cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733), provided you have `data.table` installed.

If `dat` is your data,

```
devtools::source_gist(11380733)
cSplit(dat, c("Loc", "Time"), direction = "long")
#            Loc Time
# 1:       Paris   10
# 2:  Luxembourg   15
# 3:       Paris    9
# 4:        Lyon   12
# 5:      Berlin   11
```

Comment: I was just posting the same thing :-)

Comment: In case you want to add the obvious `list` variant (since the question is unclear) I had also proposed `as.data.frame(lapply(df2, unlist))`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - isn't that the same as `as.data.frame(as.list(df2))`?

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired--but I don't think they are the same.... My test case for `df2` was: `df2 <- data.frame(
  Loc = I(list(c("Paris", "Luxembourg"), c("Paris", "Lyon", "Berlin"))), 
  "Time(h)" =  I(list(c(10, 15), c(9, 12, 11))), check.names = FALSE)`

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'll delete this so you can better explain it in your answer.

Comment: I don't think you need to do that. The OP hasn't even clarified their question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each entry in your dataframe is a character string, of the form you say above, you could do the following

```
#notice the space in ", " for the first line
newLoc<-sapply(df$Loc, function(entry) {unlist(strsplit(entry,", ", fixed=TRUE))})
#and the lack there of in the second
newTime<-sapply(df$`Time(h)`, function(entry) {unlist(strsplit(entry, ",", fixed=TRUE))})
```

I think we also need to flatten the results

```
dim(newLoc)<-NULL
dim(newTime)<-NULL
```

Then combine back into a df

```
data.frame(cbind(Loc=newLoc, `Time(h)`=newTime))
```